# find common connection like Facebook common friend

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am building a simple algorithm  to find mutual connections between two inputs but i am unable to create an efficient and fast method successfully found results which i need using for loops but that did not work with large data please help me with this i am working on from last 1 month but no success.Thanks :)

```
var data_1 = [

     {Name:"Jhon",Class:10},
     {Name:"Alex",Class:10},
     {Name:"Harry",Class:10},
     {Name:"Jack",Class:11},
     {Name:"Henry",Class:11},
     {Name:"Isaac",Class:6},
     {Name:"Austin",Class:6},
     {Name:"David",Class:6},
     {Name:"Alex",Class:6},
     {Name:"Ellis",Class:9},
     {Name:"Austin",Class:9},
     {Name:"Jamie",Class:9}

    ];


    var data_2 = [

     {Name:"Jhon",Class:10},
     {Name:"Alex",Class:10},
     {Name:"Ryan",Class:10},
     {Name:"Jack",Class:11},
     {Name:"Henry",Class:11},
     {Name:"Isaac",Class:6},
     {Name:"David",Class:6},
     {Name:"Ellis",Class:9},
     {Name:"Ryan",Class:9},
     {Name:"Jamie",Class:9}

    ];


    Input 1 = Jhon,10
    Input 2 = Ellis,9

    Step 1: find all students in same class 

    //case 1 (in this case we use Data_1)
    var input_1_child = Jhon,Alex,Harry; (all these names belongs in same class)
    var input_2_child = Ellis,Austin,Jamie;  (all these names belongs in same class)

    Find matches from step 1 childs (match if any name is common in both childs)
    Result = False ( in this case there is no common name between "input_1_child" and "input_2_child" so result is false and we move to next step 2)

    // case 2  (in this case we use Data_2)
    var input_1_child = Jhon,Alex,Ryan;
    var input_2_child = Ellis,Ryan,Jamie;   

    Find matches from step 1 childs (match if any name is common in both childs)
    Result = True ( Ryan is common name between "input_1_child" and "input_2_child" so result is true so we return data like below)

    return [[0],[2]] - [[7],[8]];

    in above result we return two diffrent array , in first array  0 refres to index value of first input and in second array 7 refres to index value of second input so first item in array will always be input index
    and 2 and 8 refres to index value of "Ryan" which is common in both childs 


    //Step 2: this will execute only when step 1 results are false

     In step 1 we find all child's of Input 1  now we go one more deep level and find child's of child like below

    from Jhon we found 2 other names which is Alex and harray now we find all child's of those two other names

    Note in this case we use "data_1" 

    [0]   => index value in data array
    Jhone => name
    :10   => class


    Input 1 => [0]Jhone:10 -> [1]Alex:10 , [2]harray:10 
                               |            |
                               |            | 
                               |       No Other harray found in data
                               |  
                              [7]Alex:6-> [5]Isaac:6, [6]David:6 


    Input 2 => [8]Ellis:9 -> [9]Austin:9 , [10]Jamie:9 
                              |            |
                              |            | 
                              |       No Other Jamie found in data
                              |  
                             [6]Austin:6-> [5]Isaac:6, [6]David:6                 


    and again match 2nd level childs of input 1 with input two and return rsults like below

    return [[0],[1],[7],[5]] - [[8],[9],[6],[5]];

**    NOTE:  if results are false in step 2 then repeat this process one more deep level child's until match found**
```

**My old solutions which works very slow**

```
public function Matrix(Request $request) {
        $list_id = $request->input('id');
        //user Input
        $input_1 = $request->input('name');
        $input_1   = explode('|', $input_1);
        $input_2 = $request->input('name2');
        $input_2   = explode('|', $input_2);
       $input_name_1   = $input_1[0];
       $input_uuid_1   = $request->input('name_one_class');
       $input_id_1    = $input_1[2];
       $input_name_2   = $input_2[0];
       $input_uuid_2   = $request->input('name_two_class');
       $input_id_2    = $input_2[2];
       $this->global_input_1_uid = $input_uuid_1;
        // case 1
       $case1_0  = Sheet::where([['uid', $input_uuid_1], ['name', $input_name_2]])->get();
       $case1_1  = Sheet::where([['uid', $input_uuid_2], ['name', $input_name_1]])->get();
       if(count($case1_0) > 0) {
           //return  $case1_0[0]->uid;
           $cfi1 = Sheet::whereIn('id',[$input_id_1])->get();
           $cfi2 = Sheet::whereIn('id',[$input_id_2])->get();
           $Mat_res = [$cfi1,$cfi2];
           return view('results')->with('data', $Mat_res)->with('name2', $input_2)->with('name', $input_1)->with('case', 0);
       }else if( count($case1_1) > 0) {
             $cfi1 = Sheet::whereIn('id',[$input_id_1])->get();
           $cfi2 = Sheet::whereIn('id',[$input_id_2])->get();
           $Mat_res = [$cfi1,$cfi2];
           return view('results')->with('data', $Mat_res)->with('name2', $input_2)->with('name', $input_1)->with('case', 0);
       }else {
       // case 2   
          $case_2_1_list = Sheet::where([['uid', $input_uuid_1]])->get();
          $case_2_2_list = Sheet::where([['uid', $input_uuid_2]])->get();
          $case_2_1_list_name_array = Sheet::where([['uid', $input_uuid_1]])->whereNotIn('id', [$input_id_1])->pluck('name')->toArray();
          $case_2_2_list_name_array = Sheet::where([['uid', $input_uuid_2]])->whereNotIn('id', [$input_id_2])->pluck('name')->toArray();
          $result_pre = array_intersect($case_2_1_list_name_array, $case_2_2_list_name_array);
          $intersection = array_intersect($case_2_1_list_name_array, $case_2_2_list_name_array);
          //$intersection = implode(',', $intersection);
           //return  $case_2_2_list_name_array;
          if($result_pre == true) {
              $Mat_res =  [$input_uuid_1,$input_uuid_2,$intersection];
              return view('results')->with('intersection', $intersection)->with('uid1', $input_uuid_1)->with('uid2', $input_uuid_2)->with('name2', $input_2)->with('name', $input_1)->with('case', 1);
         }else {
              // return $input_uuid_1.' - '.$input_uuid_2;
            // return $in_class_two;
              // get all first level childs
       //$child_1_level_1 =  Sheet::where('name', $input_1)->pluck('uid')->toArray();
       $child_1_level_1 =  Sheet::where([['uid','=', $input_uuid_1],['lid','=', 1]])->whereNotIn('name', [$input_1])->get();
      // $child_2_level_1 =  Sheet::where('name', $input_2)->pluck('uid')->toArray();
     //return $child_1_level_1;
       $child_2_level_1 =  Sheet::where('uid','=', $input_uuid_2)->whereNotIn('name', [$input_2])->where('lid', $list_id)->get();
       return $child_2_level_1;
       $nokia = Sheet::where([['name', '=', $input_name_1], ['uid', '=', $input_uuid_1]])->get();
       $sony = Sheet::where([['name', '=', $input_name_2], ['uid', '=', $input_uuid_2]])->get();
       $child_1_level_1 = $this->setRoute($nokia[0]->id, $child_1_level_1);
       $child_2_level_1 = $this->setRoute($sony[0]->id, $child_2_level_1);
       //return $child_1_level_1;
       array_push($this->final_list_1, $child_1_level_1);
       array_push($this->final_list_2, $child_2_level_1);
       array_push($this->exclude_list, 0);
       $this->matrixLoop(1);
       $this->FlaternData(1);
       $this->matrixLoop(2);
       $this->FlaternData(2);
       $matrix_result_1 = $this->theEnd(1);
       $matrix_result_2 = $this->theEnd(2);
       $a1 =  array_keys($matrix_result_1);
       $a2 =  array_keys($matrix_result_2);
       $result=array_intersect($a1,$a2);
       $Mat_res = array();
       $check = false;
       foreach ($matrix_result_1 as $key => $value) {
           if($check == true) {break;}
            foreach ($matrix_result_2 as $key2 => $value2) {
                 if($check == true) {break;}
                 if($key == $key2) {
                    //return [$value, $value2];
                    $mk1 = explode("|",$value);
                    $mk2 = explode("|",$value2);
                    $mk1str = implode(',', $mk1);
                    $mk2str = implode(',', $mk2);// ADD ARRAY REVERSE HERE ******************************************IMPOERTANT**************************** $mk2str = implode(',', array_reverse($mk2));
                    //return [$mk1,$mk2];
                    $mat1 = $this->removeRepeatedParent($mk1,$mk1str,1);
                    $mat2 = $this->removeRepeatedParent($mk2,$mk2str,2);
                    //return [$mat1,'--------------------------------------------',$mat2];
                    //$mat1 = Sheet::whereIn('id', $mk1)->orderByRaw(DB::raw("FIELD(id, $mk1str)"))->get();
                    //$mat2 = Sheet::whereIn('id', $mk2)->orderByRaw(DB::raw("FIELD(id, $mk2str)"))->get();
                    $data = [$mat1, $mat2];
                    array_push($Mat_res, $data);
                    //$check = true;
                }
            }
       }
       return view('results')->with('data', $Mat_res)->with('name2', $input_2)->with('name', $input_1)->with('case', 5);
       }
       }
    }
```

Comment: How about showing the *actual, slow code* ?

Comment: @jonasWilms ok i am updating slow code its in php

Comment: Then why is this question tagged JS / NodeJS?

Comment: because its faster and now i am working on node.js and i want solution in node and js

Comment: Then first of all rewrite that in nodejs?

Comment: not all actually i already working on node and i am successfully imported large data from excel to json now i need a logic to find mutual,  In php my all code is mesh and i know it will not work with large data so i am looking for most efficient algorithm to do this its does not matter if its node or php

Answer (score 0):

I think this explanation will help for your problem.
If you want to implement a data structure with connection,first you have to implement graph like data structure to store your data.

Graph is a non linear data structure with nodes and edges.As a example if you take facebook account,each person is a node and each node holds the information of the person.edges are the links which connect the nodes.

you can refer graphql (implemented by facebook) which is a easy way to implement your data structure and query defining by schemas.You can integrate graphql with nodejs easily.

please refer these links to get started with graphql and understand the graphs.

[Graph theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graph_theory)

[Graph Data Structure And Algorithms](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/graph-data-structure-and-algorithms/)

[Thinking in Graphs](https://graphql.org/learn/thinking-in-graphs/)